# PGFPlot: Newcommand argument Color not respected

Tags: pgfplots, color

I created a new command which prints a graph from a file. So far so good. Now I want to add (to the command) an additional argument *color*.

This is what I have so far:

```
\newcommand{\plotvtf}[4]{%
    \ifthenelse{\isempty{#4}}{
        \renewcommand{\thiscolor}{}
    }{
        \renewcommand{\thiscolor}{color=#4}
        \StrSubstitute{#4}{/tikz/}{}[\thiscolor]%
    }%
    \addplot [ultra thick, \thiscolor, mark=none, smooth] table[x index=#2, y expr={abs(\thisrowno{#3})}, skip first n={11}, header=false] {#1};
}
```

This all works for just one graph.
But if I do this with multiple files, all graphs have the same color (the color last used. In this case: *pink*):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[title=Prägestempel 1-4]
\plotvtf{./graph/praegestempel-1.vtf}{2}{4}{black}
\plotvtf{./graph/praegestempel-2.vtf}{2}{4}{red}
\plotvtf{./graph/praegestempel-3.vtf}{2}{4}{blue}
\plotvtf{./graph/praegestempel-4.vtf}{2}{4}{pink}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I don't quite understand the logic behind this....!?

Any hints and comments are appreciated.

Comment: Additional info: All graphs have the same color (namely black) if I omit the 4th argument. But if I omit the 4th argument, I expect pgfplots to color the graphs according to the predefined styles ...

Comment: How about `\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand\plotvtf{m m m O{black}}{
  \addplot [ultra thick,color=#4, mark=none, smooth] 
    table[x index=#2, y expr={abs(\thisrowno{#3})}, skip first n={11}, header=false] {#1};
}`?  This you can use like `\plotvtf{./graph/praegestempel-2.vtf}{2}{4}[red]`.

Comment: No. Unfortunately this does not work either.
I've uploaded min required files: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8DpN9H9EfbPMG43NnlSTFdpX3c/view
And the project is here as well: https://www.sharelatex.com/project/57908043197f2f1913024814

Comment: `\addplot` is stored without expansion of its options, so it's not surprising you get the last color for all.

Comment: You may try `\expandafter\addplot\expandafter[\thiscolor,ultra thick,...]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have your data file, so I will use a mathematical expression. You can use the color argument directly in the options of the plot. Then it would be possible to change not only the color but also e.g. the line style of a plot.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\newcommand{\plotvtf}[2][]{%
    \addplot+[ultra thick, mark=none, smooth,#1]{#2};
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\plotvtf[black]{x}
\plotvtf[red,dashed]{2*x}
\plotvtf[blue]{.5*x}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note the `+` after `\addplot`. With `\addplot+` the normal cycle list is used and the options in the optional argument are added. Without the `+` only the given options are used. So

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\newcommand{\plotvtf}[2][]{%
    \addplot+[ultra thick, mark=none, smooth,#1]{#2};
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\plotvtf{x}
\plotvtf{2*x}
\plotvtf{.5*x}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

results in

[image]

---

**Update**

Here is an addiitional example with your file and `\NewDocumentCommand` from `\xparse` as suggested by @HenriMenke:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand\plotvtf{m m m O{}}{
  \addplot+ [ultra thick, mark=none, smooth, #4]
    table[x index=#2, y expr={abs(\thisrowno{#3})}, skip first n={11}, header=false]
    {#1};
}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\startschneiden}{4.87}
\newcommand{\startpraegen}{2.2}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    title=Auswerfer,
    width=\linewidth,
    height=8cm,
    grid=both,  
    minor x tick num=9,
    minor y tick num=1,
    xtick distance=1,
%       ytick distance=10,
    xlabel={Distanz vor OT $\left[ mm \right] $ }, 
    ylabel={Kraft in Tonnen $\left[ t \right] $},
    x dir=reverse, % umkehren, weil mm vor OT
%       y dir=reverse, % umkehren, weil Werte negativ sind
    ymin=-0.5, % unten links beschränken
    xmax=8.35, % mm vor OT, maximum. geht dann richtung null.
    xmin=-0.05,
    x tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd, fixed, fixed zerofill, precision=1, /tikz/.cd},
    legend pos=north west,
    smooth,
    extra x ticks={\startschneiden, \startpraegen},
    extra x tick labels={Schneiden, Prägen},
    extra x tick style={x tick label style={yshift=-2ex,anchor=north, rotate=0, color=green!50!black},grid=major,major grid style={draw=green!50!black, very thick}},
    xlabel style={yshift=-3ex},
    ]

  \plotvtf{praegestempel-1.vtf}{2}{4}[black]
  \plotvtf{praegestempel-2.vtf}{2}{4}[orange]


  \legend{Präger 1, Präger 2, Präger 3, Präger 4};
  \node[draw=black, fill=white, fill opacity=0.8, text opacity=1] at (axis cs:7,4) [anchor=north west] {$F_{P max} = \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}}$};

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works now! It was all in the `\addplot+`.
In combination with Henri Menke 's answer I got what I needed.

Comment: BTW: FPmax is wrong! This is the max of the Y-AXIS! :-o
I just noticed that ... but that's a different issue.